# React JS + Возвратить в методе React::render() результат без контейнера

Tags: javascript

Добрый день!

Есть такой участок:

```
var ElementProducts = React.createClass({
    componentDidMount: function() {
        calculator.bind('change', this.listChanged);
    },
    render: function() {
        if (this.props.items) {
            var products = [];

            this.props.items.map(function(item) {
                products.push(<ElementProduct product={item} key={'product-' + item.pid} className='product' type={this.props.type}/>);
            }.bind(this));

            return (<tr>{ products }</tr>);
        } else {
            return (
                <ElementSpinner/>
                );
        }
    },
    listChanged: function() {
        this.forceUpdate();
    }
});
```

Отрисовка происходит в элементе . Т.к. в переменной products у меня и так содеражатся строки таблицы  то мне не нужнен контейнер, а заменить элемент  React JS не умеет.
Мне необходимо вернуть `{ products }` вместо `{<tr>products</tr>}`, как это сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не совсем понял вопрос. Метод render должен возвращать дерево элементов с **одним** корневым элементом.
Если ElementProducts используется в каком-то другом компоненте, таблице, например, то вам надо сделать не так. Вам нужно что бы ElementProducts (тогда его лучше назвать ElementProduct, конечно) возвращал один элемент, а перебор по this.props.items осуществлять в этой таблице.

Comment: Благодарю за ответ, это не плохое решение. Просто хотелось обойтись без такого решения. А по поводу того что не понятно, попытаюсь объяснить, может что-то ещё подскажете.

Есть компонент <ElementProduct/> - он рисует <tr>...</tr>
Есть компонент <ElementProducts/> у которого в состоянии или свойстве есть массив, проходя по которому я рисую <ElementProduct/>, т.е. на выходе я имею уйму <tr>...</tr> с разной информацией. Но я не могу вставить <ElementProducts/> в <tbody>, т.к. ему нужен какой-то html контейнер. А мне надо вернуть <ElementProducts/> без внешнего контейнера.

Comment: А может вам не нужно создать отдельный компонент для строк? Можно сделать метод renderRows, который вернет массив реактовсих элементов без контейнера. И вы его вставите в <tbody>

Comment: Может. Я вот только не понял как мне вызвать renderRows()? Поместить его в render()?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/28xbe696/ как-то так

Comment: Спасибо! То что надо!